# How to get parent and child categories from wp_nav_menu() Loop in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-rest-api

I have created a nav menu on the archive page
[image]

**I want to loop them here as foreach**
so how can do it?

```
<ul><!-- 1-->
      <li><a> First tree</a> <i class="my-icon"></i>
         <ul><!-- 2-->
            <li><a>Second Tree</a>
               <ul><!-- 3-->
                  <li><a>Third Tree</a>
                     <ul><!-- 4-->
                        <li><a>Fourth Tree</a></li>
                     </ul>
                  </li>
               </ul>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
```

Comment: Any reason you can’t just call [`wp_nav_menu`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/)?

Comment: @ChrisHaas because i want to customize with menu and add some elements between them, but wp_nav_menu just give me peremission to edit the class names.

Comment: Another option is to use `wp_get_nav_menu_items` but that will be a flat array, and you’ll have to reinvent the hierarchy.